# Create, random fill and search element on 2d array NxN Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, random

I create an array of numbers, trying to fill in their rule or random size NxN, then looking for the amount in each of the diagonals and deduce it. Help to understand the errors that I noted in the comments. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
func diagonals (n:Int) -> String{
        var sumFirst: Int
        var sumSecond: Int

        var multArray = Array(count: n, repeatedValue: Array(count: n, repeatedValue: 0))
                print(multArray) //create 2d array NxN with Initialisation

        for var i in multArray {
            for var k in multArray {
                multArray[i][k] = i+k // fill array elements the sum of the indices (error line) or we can fill it random, but how?
                if i==k { //check element on the main diagonal
                     sumFirst += multArray[i][k]  // do sum (error line)
                }
                if (i+k) == n  { //check element on secondary diagonal (error line)
                    sumSecond += multArray[i][k] // do sum (error line)
                }
            }
        }

        return "Sum elemets on main diagonal =\(sumFirst) and second =\(sumSecond)"
    }

    diagonals(3)
```

Comment: The error says `error: cannot subscript a value of type 'Array<[Int]>' (aka 'Array<Array<Int>>') with an index of type 'Array<Int>'`, because `i` and `k` are the `elements -> (arrays)` in your `multArray`, so you can't assign an array to Int, to getting closer to your goal use the [enumerate() method](http://apple.co/25pGSNq) to get also the indices of your array like this `for (indexI, elementI) in multArray.enumerate()`and also for your second for in `for (indexK, elementK) in multArray.enumerate()`

Comment: @ronatory thank you, friend! I corrected and wrote the decision in the response.

Comment: you're welcome, but I recommend also Sulthan's hint in the comments of your decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
    func diagonals (n:Int) -> String{
    var sumFirst = 0
    var sumSecond = 0

    var multArray = Array(count: n, repeatedValue: Array(count: n, repeatedValue: 0))
            print(multArray) //create 2d array NxN with Initialisation

    for indexI in multArray.indices {
        for indexK in multArray.indices {
            multArray[indexI][indexK] = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(n))) // fill array elements randomly
            if indexI==indexK { //check element on the main diagonal
                 sumFirst += multArray[indexI][indexK]  // do sum
            }
            if (indexI+indexK + 1) == n  { //check element on secondary diagonal
                sumSecond += multArray[indexI][indexK] // do sum
            }
        }
    }
print(multArray)
    return "Sum elemets on main diagonal =\(sumFirst) and second =\(sumSecond)"
}

diagonals(3)
```

Comment: Instead of `(indexI, _) in multArray.enumerate()` you probably just want to use `for indexI in multArray.indices {` or just `for index in 0..<n {`

Comment: 1) for method `for indexI in multArray.indices {` can I scan two index in one line? for example `for (indexI, indexK) in multArray.indices {`
2) for method `for index in 0..<n {` How the compiler will see that our index is exactly the index of the array? @Sulthan

Comment: Not easily but you can iterate over one index and convert it to two indices. Something similar to `let indices = (0..<(n * n)).map { ($0 / n, $0 % n) }` and then `for (row, column) in indices {`. However, note that the division there will affect the performance if used with big data.

Comment: yeah..that's not good...so what about second question?@Sulthan

Comment: I don't understand your question. The compiler is not checking integer indices.